# Remove "index" in URL for static website using AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am hosting a static website using AWS S3, with the default file being under the following URL: *mywebsite.com/index* (I successfully removed the .html).

However, I would like to display *mywebsite.com* instead - so without the trailing /index.

Is it possible? If so, how to do it? Thanks!

**Edit**: screenshot added
[image]

Comment: I think you need some tool to `rewrite URL`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following documentation help you to set the default root document of a given bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html

Comment: Yes, index.html is already the default root document. However, when typing mywebsite.com in the URL bar, it returns me a 404 error.

Comment: What is your default root object? Please copy and paste from the s3 onfiguration.

Comment: It need to be `index.html` as specified in the documentation.

Comment: Aaaah so following advice from another post, I initially changed the file name from _index.html_ to _index_ to remove the trailing _.html_ from the URL. That being said, indeed, by setting the document to index.html and ditto for the Default Root Object, it works. Thanks a lot!